# How can i remove decimal point in python

Tags: python, integer, decimal

I have a variable like follow

`a[i] = b`

and b is integer number like 2

but if I do `print(a[i])`, it shows 2.0

Can I remove the decimal point?

Comment: Include the contents of `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use type conversion on your result to convert it to an int and it would work. Without further information about contents of `a`:

```
print(int(a[i]))
```

Comment: It works surely but why does it show decimal value? even though i write a[i]=int(b) it shows decimal value

Comment: @YouHur I don't know why it does it for you. For me it works exactly as you would assume it does. What have you done with `a` before? although it really souldn't matter.

Comment: a is a numpy array. It is a = np.empty([d,1]) then a[i] should show a value which is fed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the int() function in python.
If you print(int(a[i])) it will show 2 not 2.0

```
a = [2.0,3.0]
for i in range(len(a)):
  print(int(a[i]))
```

and the output is:

```
    2
    3
```